# custom matrix in NMF in scikit-learn

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, nmf

I've to do NMF with sklearn, I've used the instructions here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html

I want to add my initialized matrix H, there is option to do init='custom' but I don't know how to give him the matrix H.
I've tried:

```
model = NMF(n_components=2, init='custom',H=myInitializationH random_state=0);
```

but it doesn't work.

In addition, is someone know how to fix my matrix and update only W?

edit:

Thanks for the answer

When I choose the custom option, I get the error:

```
ValueError: input contains nan infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

However, the matrix don't contains any nan or infinity.
Moreover, I did it for very small matrix to see if it is fine and its not:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

x=np.ones((2,3));
#model = NMF(n_components=1, init='custom', solver='mu',beta_loss=1,max_iter=500,random_state=0,alpha=0,verbose=0, shuffle=False);
model = NMF(n_components=1, init='custom');
fixed_W = model.fit_transform(x,H=np.ones((1,3)));
fixed_H = model.components_;

print(np.matmul(fixed_W,fixed_H));
```

I got the same error unless I do 'random' instead of 'custom'.

Is it happen also to you? why is it happen?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is a comma missing after H=myInitializationH, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the W and H in `fit()` or `fit_transform()`.

As per the [documentation of `fit_transform()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html#sklearn.decomposition.NMF.fit_transform):-

> ```
> W : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_components)
>     If init=’custom’, it is used as initial guess for the solution.
>
> H : array-like, shape (n_components, n_features)
>     If init=’custom’, it is used as initial guess for the solution.
> ```

Same applies for `fit()`.

Do something like:

```
model.fit(X, H=myInitializationH, W=myInitializationW)
```

Update:
Seems like if you pass the `init='custom'` param, you need to supply both W and H. If you provide H and not W, it will be taken as None, and then throw an error.

Comment: @kalonymus That depends on your data. Is your data correct. According to the error, it contains some missing info or some infinite values.

Comment: the data is correct, I did test case with 3X2 matrix only with only 1 component and it is still have problem. please see the edited post

Comment: @kalonymus Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I did. I've also voted for you but it is not publicly displayed because this is new user and I dont have enough reputations. Anyway, you are totaly deserve it. Thank you!